# AWS: Problem with publishing SNS messages by RDS Snapshot creation event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-sns

I'm trying to subscribe RDS snapshot creation events and proxy them to SNS.

As [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.html), I've set up the RDS event subscription which subscribes the `creation` event of any `db-snapshot` and proxies it to the SNS topic.

After creating snapshots manually via AWS RDS console, although I checked Cloud Watch Metrics of the SNS topic, the `NumberOfMessagesPublished` parameter of the topic would not make any increase.

My RDS event subscription config is as below,

- target: sns-topic
- source type: all db-snapshot
- event category: creation

The access policy of the SNS topic allows `SNS:*` action for `AWS: *` principal.

Comment: Can you maybe subscribe to the topic via e-Mail to check if notifications are sent? According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.html) you seem to be doing it right and should see the `RDS-EVENT-0040` and `RDS-EVENT-0042` events. Is the source type `all` or `db-snapshot`?